# Mobile menu not working - jQuery error?

Tags: menus, jquery, mobile

I did some heavy editing to a free Wordpress theme and somehow the mobile menu doesn't work anymore.

http://www.liveaerosmith.com

I tried to see what the problem was but it must have happened a while back and I don't know which of my changes ended up ruining the mobile menu.

Can anyone see it? And maybe let me know the process of identifying the culprit. Thanks!

Comment: I suspect there is no click handler attached to the menu on mobile, but since there is no code in your question, it's impossible to debug. Have you tried going by commit by commit in version control to figure out at which point it broke?

Comment: I can't really go back, I don't know when the problem occured, may be months ago :( I didn't include the whole code, I included the URL so you can see the whole code there.

Comment: mobile menu seems to be working for me on Firefox.

Comment: How you were able to detect your problem? what was the solution? I'm facing the same problem